# Always-on clock

Tags: cyanogenmod, clock, super-amoled, daydream

I have a rooted device with an Amoled screen and Android 5.1 (CyanogenMod 12.1) installed. I would like to also use it as a desk/night clock. I know that with the Daydream (‘screensaver’) feature, I can get this, but only while charging, or docked.

- Is it possible to allow Daydream also while on battery?
- If not, is there another option?
- Optional extra requirement: Ideally, the screen would turn of completely when it is covered.

I prefer ‘simple’ solutions, but am also interested in ones that are more complicated and involve, e.g., some form of automation. (They may also be of interest to others.)

Comment: @beeshyams: Can you put your answer in an answer?

Comment: You can try [Day Dream](http://apps.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.org.vijai.daydream/6/9585919/Daydream) . It is not on play store but install via [Aptoide](http://m.aptoide.com/?lang=en)

Comment: were you able to check it out?

Comment: No, but it is a good suggestion. Given that it only (officially) supports Android <5 and the fact that it is not on the Play store mean that I will most likely not try it.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for this quite some time ago... Turns out you don't need any complicated apps for this. Get [Daydream Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brianco.daydreamlauncher). Does not satisfy optional requirements but is already awesome.

EDIT: Totally forgot that additional settings (including duration) requires [Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brianco.daydreamlauncherplus) (99 cents). My bad.

Comment: The daydreaming does not persist, it stops after a short while (sleep timeout?).

Comment: @equaeghe Click the "Daydream" shortcut in launcher to start the persistent daydream.

Comment: That is what I did, it does not persist.

Comment: @equaeghe Look inside "Daydream Settings" and set "Daydream sleep" to desired time value. If that doesn't work either then I have no idea what's with your device.

Comment: I do not have that setting, just one to start daydreaming right away and to select when to daydream (docked, charging, either). The general sleep timeout does determine how long the immediately started daydream will last, but it can't go over 30 min and moreover, I do not want to set this to another value.

Comment: Uhh... I mean the "Daydream Settings" shortcut in your launcher.

Comment: I did not find this “Daydream Settings” shortcut, there is only the “Daydream” shortcut itself (and the widget, which does the same thing, launch daydream). Can you provide more information about this, perhaps also in your answer?

Comment: @equaeghe Ugh, dammit, forgot I have the Plus version, settings is only available for Plus... Sorry, support the dev if you want to, or use beeshyams's solution if not.